# Converting "is null" into a linq to sql statement

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am having trouble replicating the following sql as a LINQ statement

```
select TableA.* from TableA left outer join TableAinTableB on TableA.Id = TableAId where TableBId is null
```

The following returns no lines

```
from TableA in db.TableA join AinB in db.TableAinTableB on TableA.Id equals TableAId where AinB.TableBId == null select TableA
```

Also tried and a few other things that didn't work.

```
from TableA in db.TableA join AinB in db.TableAinTableB on TableA.Id equals TableAId where AinB == null select TableA
```

TableAinTableB is a many to many table.  The query I want will pull all the records from TableA that have no records in the middle table.  My sql does what I want but I have no idea how to convert it to LINQ to SQL.

I ended up working around it by just doing a db.ExecuteQuery("working sql"); But I would like to know if the query is possible in LINQ and how to write it, or a pointer to a document that covers this scenario. My searching did not uncover anything I found useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx) to simulate an outer join.
Check out this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737929.aspx).

In your example it's something like:

```
var q = from a in TableA
            join b in TableB on a.Id equals b.Id into g
            from b in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select a;
```

Comment: Doesn't give the same output as the sql, it does the outer join but without the filter.

Comment: Do you want only the null Ids? I think you can just add: where b.Id == null

Comment: b.Id==null gives an always false warning, as it should as b.Id is a not null field.  I think I will just stick with my executequery solution

Answer (score 1):

For "IS NULL" try something like this

```
from TableA in db.TableA 
join AinB in db.TableAinTableB 
on TableA.Id equals TableAId 
where object.Equals(AinB.TableBId, null)
select TableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ExecuteQuery` method of LINQ, for example:

```
string query = "select TableA.* from TableA left outer join TableAinTableB on TableA.Id = TableAId where TableBId is null";
TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext();
IEnumerable<TableA> objUser = db.ExecuteQuery<TableA>(query).ToList();
```

where `TestDataContext` is the LINQ-to-SQL `DataContext` for the database in which `TableA` is mapped.