# using LINQ Lambda expressions get columns having values NULL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i want to get result where a column values are NULL using LINQ Expressions

```
search.AddCriteria(x => x.LogStatus == 
Inventory.AffStatusToChar((EAffidavitLogStatus)byte.Parse(cmbLog.SelectedValue)));

public void AddCriteria (Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria) {
        if (_where == null) { _where = w => true; }
        _where = And(criteria);
    }


private Expression<Func<T, bool>> And (Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(
                _where.Body,
                Expression.Invoke(expr, _where.Parameters.Cast<Expression>())
            ), _where.Parameters);
    }

//This below part is use to execute the Linq
//IQueryable<T> result = db.GetTable<T>();
//result = result.Where(_where);
```

result's where part is looking like `WHERE ([t0].[LogStatus]) = @p5)`
see i want `IS NULL`

I want query like this

```
SQL query : `select * from xyz where abc is NULL`
```

but the LINQ expression above is converting to 
    `select * from xyz where abc=NULL` which gives a different result.

any one gone through this kind a problem? how can `IS NULL` in LINQ expression achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting "is null" into a linq to sql statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502328/converting-is-null-into-a-linq-to-sql-statement)

Comment: 1st that question is not solved and 2nd that question is not about `Expression`

Comment: @Ray: AddCriteria is a method m using to filter out my search, this method takes lamda expression. Now `IQueryable<T> result = db.GetTable<T>();` this gives me search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i figured it myself here is the solution what i did

```
search.AddCriteria(x => !(x.LogStatus!=null));
```

this returns query like

```
WHERE (NOT (UNICODE([t0].[LogStatus]) IS NULL ))
```

tada!! this is what i expected..

Comment: Interesting. Why the double negation?

Answer (score -1):

hey you can check this post [(Linq and Nullable Values) OR ( SQL ISNULL with LINQ)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/linq-and-nullable-values-or-sql-isnull.html)

you can try out

```
var user = from u in Users
join uc in UserClients on u.Id equals uc.UserId
into myuserwithclient
from m in myuserwithclient.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
 Id=u.Id,
 FirstName=u.FirstName,
 LastName=u.LastName,
 UserId=m.UserId,
 MobileNo = m.MobileNo  ?? "N/A"
};
var nullvalues = user.where( u=>u.MobileNo== "N/A");
```